# Changing hover to click on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am having trouble changing the function to be called on 'click' rather than 'hover'. I have tried changing 'hover' to 'click' as well as 'toggle' with no positive results

```
$('#menu li').hover(
    function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({height: '100px'},1000,function(){});
            $(this).find('div').show(600);
        }
    ,
    function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({height: '20px'},1000,function(){});
        } 
  );
```

Do I have to bind the event if I want to change it to 'click'? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/52/

```
var clicked = 0;
$('#menu li').click(
   function(){
        if(clicked === 0){
            $(this).stop().animate({height: '100px'},1000,function(){});
            $(this).find('div').show(600);
            clicked = 1;
        } else if(clicked === 1){
            $(this).stop().animate({height: '20px'},1000,function(){});  
            clicked = 0;
        }
    }
 );
```

set a variable to keep track of clicked state

Comment: what if I wanted the menu to be wider than the button?

Comment: you would have to add more styles to specifically target the buttons width versus the items width that slide down.. OR it might involve setting up your menu with nested ul lists ... usually menus are made with nested ul lists to create horizontal or vertical menus

Comment: @m_p -- for time sake here is a nice tut to get the idea what i mean by nesting ul lists -- http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/flat-dropdown-menu-tutorial --

Answer (score 1):

You are passing two parameters to `$(...).click(clickHandle)`. Just pass one function.

Check http://api.jquery.com/click/

In two arguments case,

```
http://api.jquery.com/click/
```

Comment: im not sure I understand, do I need to just get rid of one of those two anonymous functions and change animate to toggle?

Comment: what do you want to happen? just put all in just one function

Comment: I guess PAPARFRESH's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)  needs only one argument when I changed that all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`hover()` takes two callbacks, one for `mouseenter` and one for `mouseleave`. If you want to change it to click, and the first click starts the first animation and the second starts the second one, you need to add a state variable to determine whether your element has been clicked once or twice.

```
$('#menu li').click(
function(){
        if(this.clicked)
        {
         //callback 1
        }
        else
       {
        //callback 2
       }
       this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    }
```

);