# Change Drop Down Menu Section From Hover to Click

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hover, click

I am almost done making a site for my friend: www.soundpie.org 
However he now want's to change the sections which drop down from the navigation menu.
He wants to make the sections stay open on click rather then on hover.
I believe the solution lies in adding Jquery to the site.
I've tried following this post (see link bellow) but can't seem to configure the jquery

[Changing hover to click on menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324960/changing-hover-to-click-on-menu)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is thecurrent html:

```
<body>

<span id="dummy"></span>

<div id="topnav" class="tnav">

 <ul class="tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar">
      <div class="tnav-lvl1-menu-body tnav-bg4">

<div id="logo1">
      <li class="tnav-style-1">
            <div class="grow img"> <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="images/icons/ai1.png" alt="flute"><span>HEAR</span></a></div>

<div class="tnav-play animated fadeInDown">

           <div id="services" class="lightstyle">
                <div class="mustard-bg">

                     <div class="tnav-showbox">                              

                         <div id="hear-content">

                         <h2>Hear:</h2>
                          <hr>
                          <div id="video-left">
                                <img src="images/als/ail1.jpg">
                          </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.tnav-lvl1-menu li:hover .tnav-play, .tnav-lvl1-menu li:hover .tnav-play-2, .tnav-      lvl1-menu li:hover .tnav-play-3,
.tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar li:hover .tnav-play, .tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar li:hover .tnav-play-2,     .tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar li:hover .tnav-play-3,
.tnav-lvl1-menu li:hover .tnav-play-bottom, .tnav-lvl1-menu li:hover .tnav-play-2-bottom, .tnav-lvl1-menu li:hover .tnav-play-3-bottom,
.tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar li:hover .tnav-play-bottom, .tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar li:hover .tnav-play-2-bottom, .tnav-lvl1-menu-tbar li:hover .tnav-play-3-bottom {
display:block;
```

Comment: You could get fancy and use a checkbox the `:checked` selector is CSS.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only `li` are allowed as direct children of `ul`

Answer (score 0):

Could does something like this.

```
<style>
    /*
        Normal navigation styles assumed here.
        (displays, positions, floats, etc.)
    */
    nav li {
        position: relative;
    }
    nav li > input[type=checkbox] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0
        z-index: 1; /* Moves checkbox above 'a' blocking 'a' click. */
    }
    nav li > input[type=checkbox]:checked + ul {
        /*
            Move may have different display stlyes,
            but likely something similar too:
        */
        left: 0;
    }
</style>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Click</a>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here an older version of my navigation utility. http://l33t.roydukkey.com/nav-demo/
You will see that the "More" item doesn't toggle until clicked, but the others toggle on hover.

More info: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Comment: Thanks Roy, so would I just replace  :hover with :checked in CSS?

Comment: Yup. The same styles that are used on `a:hover` can be triggered by `input:checked`. Combined the selection should be something like, `a:hover + ul, input:checked + ul`.